# Sort string array according to priority array

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, .net-core

I have a priority list

```
List<string> priority = new List<string>() {
              "boss",
              "Project owner",
              "client",
              "manager",
              "client1",
              "client2 ",
              "Intern",
          };
```

and i want to sort other array according to this priority

```
List<string> arr = new List<string>(){ "client1", "boss", "manager" }
priority.Sort(arr);
```

it should return ["boss", "manager", "client1"]

note: There can be other items which are not in Priority so we can put them in last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an anonymous list with `Value` and `Order` (Get the index from the `priority` array) properties.
2. Order by descending for those which `Order` is not -1 first. Those `Order` with -1 will be placed at last.
3. Then order by `Order` (ascending).
4. Get the `Value` only to return a list of strings.

```cs
List<string> sortedArr = arr.Select(x => new 
    {
        Value = x,
        Order = priority.IndexOf(x)
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Order != -1)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Order)
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3lX4A6)

Comment: Thank you, sir. It worked (priority items at top and other at last in ascending order).

Answer (score 2):

In the `priority list`, the `client 1` item apparently has an extra space. However, you can sort the array `according to the index in the priorit` list:

```
        List<string> priority = new List<string>() {
          "boss",
          "Project owner",
          "client",
          "manager",
          "client1",
          "client2 ",
          "Intern",
      };

     List<string> arr = new List<string>() { "client1", "boss", "manager" };

     var result= arr.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(priority.ToArray(), x)).ToList();
```

Comment: I will say this is not a correct answer. According to the OP you should put the item not exist in the priority to the last position but the code you post now will move it to the first

Comment: @MichaelMao I think the question is that there is no item that is not in the list. Although it has not been talked about

Comment: sorry ,but this logic puts the least important priority items to the top.

Answer (score 1):

I used this, and I got the correct result. I was wondering if it contains any corner cases left or  any flaws still left.

```
  List<string> priority = new List<string>() {
          "boss",
          "Project owner",
          "client",
          "manager",
          "client1",
          "client2 ",
          "Intern",
      };

  List<string> arr = new List<string>() { "client1", "boss", "manager" };

  arr.Sort((a, b) => {
      if (priority.Contains(a))
           {
              return -1;
           };
       if (priority.Contains(b))
          {
             return 1;
          };
     return 0;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-7.0) to sort.

```
List<string> priority = new List<string>() {
        "boss",
        "Project owner",
        "client",
        "manager",
        "client1",
        "client2 ",
        "Intern",
    };

List<string> arr = new List<string>() { "client1", "boss", "manager" };
List<string> sortedArr = arr.OrderBy(x => priority.IndexOf(x)).ToList();
```

There was a typo in your code, `client 1` should be `client1` in the `priority`  list.

Comment: You just changed the name of the result variable to sortedArr :)

Comment: @hosseinsabziani I saw your code after posting mine. I can also say the same thing that you just changed my code

Comment: Sorry, but similar to hossien answer, your logic also puts the least important priority items to the top.

Comment: @gouravm sorry I missed that point, Yes I can see your answer.